# How To Take average of Two EPOCH Fields in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hadoop2

How to Take Average to two EPOCH time fields in Hadoop ?

Values are in the following format (1235000501, 1235000081)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to have this:

```
MIN(ts1, ts2) + ABS(ROUND((ts1-ts2)/2))
```

?